# SELECT with WHERE clause from another table

Tags: mysql, join, select, where-clause

I have to MYSQL-Tables as you can see in the screenshot.
A table with the names of the pictures, a table with the picture-category and a table with the articles.

I want to show all pictures of a certain category with status "1" in the table "artikel".

My SQL-Statement so far:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 
                    "SELECT c.category_id,c.category_name,
                            c.category_date,COUNT(photo_id)
                    FROM bilder_kat as c
                        LEFT JOIN bilder as p ON p.photo_category = c.category_id
                    GROUP BY c.category_id
                    WHERE Status='$Status_Select'
                    ORDER BY c.category_date ASC");
```

How do I get the connection to the "artikel"-database?

[image]

Comment: Add another join? Also please add tables as text to the question rather than images.

Comment: WHERE before GROUP BY

Comment: Indeed, I tried once again and now it works with another join.  

```$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT c.category_id,c.category_name,c.category_date,COUNT(photo_id)
      FROM bilder_kat as c
      LEFT JOIN bilder as p ON p.photo_category = c.category_id
      LEFT JOIN artikel as a ON a.id = c.category_id 
      WHERE a.status=$Status_Select
      GROUP BY c.category_id
      ORDER BY c.category_date ASC");
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!